# how to update the column of a table by find duplicate row record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing 3 columns.

```
Id    email1    email2
01   abc@x.com   
01                cdf@y.com
01   pwe@y.com
02   ert@x.com
03                ghu@x.com
03   cdf@y.com
04   oiu@x.com    ghy@y.com
```

I want to update the same table having expected output/result as

```
Id    email1       email2
01    abc@x.com    cdf@y.com
01    pwe@y.com
02    ert@x.com
03    cdf@y.com    ghu@x.com
04    oiu@x.com
```

Is there any way to create a view which can select the data and display the expected output/result?

Example:

```
Id    email1       email2
01    abc@x.com    
01                 cdf@y.com
01    pqr@v.com
01                 scf@y.com
01    dfg@r.com
01    fgt@r.com
01                  hji@r.com
01    gty@t.com
```

My output should come like

```
Id     email1     email2
01     abc@x.com  cdf@y.com
01     pqr@v.com  scf@scf.com
01     dfg@r.com
01     fgt@r.com 
01     gty@t.com  hji@r.com
```

basically my requirement is:the ID and the either of the eamils get updated or i want to present it on the condtion which exists as:

case 1

```
Id   enmail     email2
01   abc@x.com  
01              scf@fg.com
```

or
case 2

```
Id    email1    email2
01              fgt@r.com
01    hji@r.com
```

as, My expected o/p should be like given below in either of the case

case 1 o/p

```
Id   email1     email2
01   abc@x.com  scf@fg.com
```

case 2 o/p

```
Id    email1      email2
01    hji@r.com   fgt@r.com
```

I hope.. my requirement is clear now.

Comment: I found something which goes in desired direction but not fully your output: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5132e/28) `select distinct Id,
  first_value(email1 ignore nulls) over (partition by ID order by email1 nulls first rows between current row and unbounded following) as mail1,
  first_value(email2 ignore nulls) over (partition by ID order by email2 nulls first rows between current row and unbounded following) as mail2
from table1
order by 1`

Comment: Thanks! buddy. I got a close to, complete solution of my problem. Actually, in my stated problem, an ID can hold a max of 2 email ids. so for  ID-1 (of rownum 1,2) email ids are coming as expected (01 abc@x.com cdf@y.com)  but the ID-1(of rownum 3) is also coming as (01 pwe@y.com cdf@y.com). I dont want to cdf@y.com to come for it..

Comment: I'm sorry but your change isn't at all clear. Why is `hji` attached to `gty` and not `fgt`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the second column is non-unique when joined back to the first. So, you need to make it unique by, for instance, using the analytic function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF51719)

```
select a.id, a.email1, b.email2
  from ( select id, email1
              , row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) as r
           from table1
          where email1 is not null
                ) a
  left outer join 
       ( select id, email2
              , row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) as r
           from table1
          where email2 is not null
                ) b
   on a.id = b.id
  and a.r = b.r
order by a.id, a.email1, b.email2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5132e/38)

This is a slightly curious way to both store and represent data. It might make more sense to have a single e-mail column, which you insert all your e-mails in. You can then just select everything.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my problem is to update either of the emails column when ids are repeated.any ID can have max of 2 values in email(email1 and email2), If the same ID is repeated for the next row, i dont need updation in my row.  I hope you get it what i want to say. I am updating my code for clear requirement.